# AngularJS Filter values routine does not work when null

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a view with a table that I want to be able to filter what is displayed based on a filtered string entered by the user.  The one problem that I am running into is that the fields could be null so my filter does not work.

```
var quoteNameFilter = function () {

    return function (quotes, filterValue) {
        if (!filterValue) return quotes;

        var matches = [];
        filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
        for (var i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++) {
            var quote = quotes[i];
            if (quote.rfq.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1 ||
                quote.comments.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1 ||
                quote.priority.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1 ||
                quote.customer.customerName.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1 ||
                quote.status.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1) {

                matches.push(quote);
            }
        }
        return matches;
    };
};
```

quote.comments could be null, so how do I check if the value is null in this routine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just ensure the `quote.comments` is a `true` value using `&&` operator:

```
(quote.comments && quote.comments.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1) || ...
```